# Making a specific part of table bold

Tags: vba, ms-word

Im altering the code of a Script that is used to automatically paste an outlook signature based on AD. Now im having some problems with making the formatting work

I have one cell that contains most of the usefull information but i need the firstname and Lastname to be bold. And the other info on the same lines and below it to follow the format info that was given above it

I tried seperating the code in different cells but the formatting goes all wrong then

```
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = strFirstName & " " & strLastName & " | " & strTitle & Chr(11) & strDepartment & Chr (11) & Chr(11) & strAdress & ", " & strPostal &  " " & strCity & Chr (11) & "T" &  " " & strPhone & strTelefoon & Chr (11) & "E " & strEmail
```

strFirstName and strLastName should be in bold

Comment: How are you putting this into the Email - if you're updating the `.HTMLBody` directly, then `<b>Bold Text Here</b>` is simple enough.  If you're converting a sheet/range to HTML and copying across then look at formatting `Range.Characters([Start],[Length])` instead

Comment: Something like this ? objTable.cell(1, 2).Range.Characters(1,23).Font.Bold = True ? The code is directly put in outlook as objSignatureObject. Thanks for the help already but doesn`t make anything bold for me

Comment: `objTable.Cells(1,2).Characters(1,23).Font.Bold = True` should make the first 23 characters bold.  `objTable.Cells(1,2).Range.Characters(1,23).Font.Bold = True` should throw an "Argument not Optional" error.  And trying to track the code you've cribbed (more of the code is required to make this a [mcve]) you're actually working with a [`Word.EmailSignature` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.emailsignature)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
With objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range
  .Text = strFirstName & " " & strLastName & " | " & strTitle & Chr(11) & _
  strDepartment & Chr(11) & Chr(11) & _
  strAdress & ", " & strPostal & " " & strCity & Chr(11) & _
  "T" & " " & strPhone & strTelefoon & Chr(11) & _
  "E " & strEmail
  .End = .Start + InStr(.Text, " | ") - 1
  .Font.Bold = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers!

I fixed it by going with .select

```
objTable.Cell(1,2).select
objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
objSelection.Font.Size = "11"
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(23,68,153)
If strFirstName <> "" Then
            objSelection.Font.Bold = True
            objSelection.TypeText strFirstName & " " & strLastName
            objSelection.Font.Bold = False
End If
If strTitle <> "" Then
    ObjSelection.TypeText " | " & strTitle 
End If
ObjSelection.TypeText (Chr(11))
ObjSelection.TypeText strDepartment 
ObjSelection.TypeText (Chr(11))
If strFirstName <> "" Then
            objSelection.Font.size = 5
            objSelection.TypeText " "
            objSelection.Font.size = 11
End If
ObjSelection.TypeText (Chr(11))
ObjSelection.TypeText strAdress & ", " & strPostal &  " " & strCity
ObjSelection.TypeText (Chr(11))
If strPhone <> "" Then
            objSelection.Font.Bold = True
            objSelection.TypeText "T " 
            objSelection.Font.Bold = False
End If
ObjSelection.TypeText strPhone 
If strGSM <> "" Then
            objSelection.TypeText " | " 
            objSelection.Font.Bold = True
            objSelection.TypeText " G " 
            objSelection.Font.Bold = False
End If
ObjSelection.TypeText strTelefoon 
ObjSelection.TypeText (Chr(11))
If strEmail <> "" Then
            objSelection.Font.Bold = True
            objSelection.TypeText "E " 
            objSelection.Font.Bold = False
            objSelection.TypeText strEmail
End If
```

Comment: @Aaron_Desmedt Using selections is both unnecessary and inefficient. The code I posted is way more efficient and is also much less likely to produce screen flicker.